# How can I mock only some data services in my Angular2 app?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, module, mocking

I have a multi module Angular2 application in which I need to mock some data providers (the endpoints don't exist yet).

I have a functioning MockBackend provider which I have tried injecting in:

- the shared module that the data service resides in
- the module that uses the data service
- the component uses the data service

The first two resulted in the MockBackend taking over all http requests.  The latter threw DI errors.

I could do with some guidance on how to inject separate instances.

Comment: Try [angular-in-memory-web-api](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api). You can just [disable collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864535/2587435) as they get implemented on the backend.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, this looks really useful and much easier to implement than MockBackend.  I'm definitely going to look at using this.

Comment: Quick note, I'm still eager to discover how to inject separate instances

Comment: You can't for MockBackend because there is only one Http. You need to create a separate Https, using a different _token_ than `Http`. This means that you will be injecting two different Https (maybe Http and MockHttp), which you means you will have a lot of cleaning up to do when backend endpoints are done.

Comment: If you're unsure what I mean by "token", see [this](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-tokens) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40019237/2587435)

Comment: urgh, that's awful news.. thanks for the education though, it answers the problems I've been having

Comment: I don't want to say you _can't_, because you probably could. You could extend the MockBackend, passing the real XHRBackend to it and keep a reference to it. You can make the decision  as to use mock data or send the real request. This is pretty much what the in-memory-api does, except it doesn't use the MockBackend, it uses its own custom backend.