# HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule Error. Can I have two?

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing, httpclient

Im trying to implement two different databases of objects (emotions & faces). But when I implement both at once in app.module.ts, I get the error in my console of:

***"{body: {…}, url: "api/emotions", headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"}"***

Works fine with just one.
If I parse both into the same forRoot. i get:

***error TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.***

**app.module.ts**

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
 import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
 import { EmotionsComponent } from './emotions.component';
 import { EmotionSearchComponent } from './emotion-search.component';
 import { EmotionDetailComponent } from './emotion-detail.component';
 import { FaceService } from 'face.service';
 import { FacesComponent } from './faces.component';
 import { FaceSearchComponent } from './face-search.component';
 import { FaceDetailComponent } from './face-detail.component';
 import { EmotionService } from 'emotion.service';
 import { MessageService } from 'message.service';
 import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

 import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
 import { InMemoryDataService }  from 'in-memory-data.service';
 import { InMemoryDataFaceService }  from 'in-memory-data-face.service';



 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
     AppComponent,
     LoginComponent,
     DashboardComponent,
     EmotionsComponent,
     EmotionSearchComponent,
     EmotionDetailComponent,
     FacesComponent,
     FaceSearchComponent,
     FaceDetailComponent,

   ],
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     HttpClientModule,
      HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot( InMemoryDataService : true, { dataEncapsulation: false } )
      HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot( InMemoryDataFaceService, { dataEncapsulation: false } )


   ],
   providers: [ EmotionService, FaceService, MessageService ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

**in-memory-data.service.ts**

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {

  createDb() {
    const emotions = [
      { id: 11, name: 'HAPPY' },
      { id: 12, name: 'SAD' },
      { id: 13, name: 'ANGRY' },
      { id: 14, name: 'EXCITED' },
      { id: 15, name: 'ANXIOUS' },

    ];
    return {emotions};


}
}
```

**in-memory-data-face.service.ts**

```
 import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

 export class InMemoryDataFaceService implements InMemoryDbService {

   createDb() {
     const faces = [
       { id: 11, name: 'HAPPY2' },
       { id: 12, name: 'SAD2' },
       { id: 13, name: 'ANGR2Y' },
       { id: 14, name: 'EXCITED' },
       { id: 15, name: 'ANXIOUS' },
       { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
       { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
       { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
       { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
       { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
     ];
     return {faces};
     }
     }
```

Comment: What does the true represents in the below config?                                             HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot( InMemoryDataService : true, { dataEncapsulation: false } )

Comment: Apologies, that true is not supposed to be there I was just trying something out.

Comment: No worries, did you try again by removing it? did it worked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you cannot have two declarations of HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot like below, since The forRoot() configuration method takes an InMemoryDataService and from the look at the api it does not accept an array.

```
HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot( InMemoryDataService : true, { dataEncapsulation: false } )
HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot( InMemoryDataFaceService, { dataEncapsulation: false } )
```

What I suggest is to have only one InMemoryDataService which returns two services.

```
createDb() {
  let service1 = [];
  let service2 = [];
  return { service1, service1 }
}
```

you can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855221/angular-2-multiple-http-services) which implements in a similar fashion. I guess it's also a cleaner way to implement, [here](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/issues/68) is another example of implementing two services in the same data service.

```
OPINIONATED - but do you really need to do this?
```

Do you intended to show the images on screen? I think you can store the images in img folder in your project and provide it's url in the data service which in turn you can use it once the you get the response.

```
let images = [
      { id: 1, path: 'img/image1.png', },
      { id: 2, path: 'img/image1.png', },
      { id: 3, path: 'img/image1.png', },
      { id: 4, path: 'img/image1.png' }
    ];
```

And in UI

```
<ul>  
  <li *ngFor="#img of images">
    <img src="{{ img.path }}" />
  </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Just curious, is there any way to have a service of images?

Comment: I updated the answer for you, note that it's opinionated, and you are not really serving raw images but only the path of the image that's located in your project folder where you use that path to load the image on UI, but do you really have serve images like this?

Comment: Thanks for the help. That method of adding a path to the service didnt work. Im open to suggestions into another method of serving images? Thanks, really struggling with this.

Comment: Were you seeing any specific errors? may be in browser logs?  for example if the path to the image is '/assets/images/therealdealportfoliohero.jpg' you could use <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img [src]="path to image">
    </div>
</div>

Comment: If that does not work, can you create a new question with the code you are using to load images?